# UITextField is not responding

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I'm experiencing some problems with `UITextField` inside a `UITableViewCell`.
Things are working well until I open the iOS media player, watch a short movie and going back to my view.

Then, I'm trying to click on the `UITextField`, but nothing happens and it does not responds to my clicks.

In the same screen (it's a `UITableView`), I have a switch button (in another row), which is working fine after switching views.

My view is implementing the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol and `textFieldShouldReturn` in particular.
My implementation of `textFieldShouldReturn` is a simple call to : `[textField resingFirstResponder]`

I'll appriciate any thoughts or ideas why it happens and how to solve it.

Thanks!
koby

Comment: Have you tried [tableView reload]; when you return from your movie clip?

Comment: Have you put anything in the -didSelectRowForIndexPath to see if it is getting in there? Has the media player fully resigned itself?

Comment: didSelectRowForIndexPath didn't work for the rows with the textfield. it did work for the row with the switch. about the mediaplayer - what do you mean about the resignation ? I didn't do anything special with it.

Comment: [mediaplayer resignFirstResponder] didn't help..

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, what fixed it for me was to make sure to return the correct height for the table view cell. Check your heightForRowAtIndexPath function - even though you can see all the objects in your cell they may be outside of a clickable/tappable area.

Comment: Thank you boss. This solved my issue. Thanks a lot for letting me to enough sleep to night.